# Core Data stack with only a single context initialized with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm working on an app that requires multiple asynchronous downloads and saving of their contents to Core Data entities.  One of the downloads is large and noticed the UI was being blocked while creating/writing to the managed object context. My research led me to read up on concurrent Core Data setups and I started implementing one of these. But I'm running into issues and spending a lot of time correcting things.

Before I continue, I'm thinking about simply setting up a single MOC with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.  Nothing I read mentions doing this.  This way I could optionally perform MOC operations in the background, or just use the main thread as usual while maintaining a single MOC.

Is this a good approach?  If not, what is wrong with it?  I doubt this is the right approach because if it is, `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` dominates `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and there would be no reason to have the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` MOC for background tasks.

But you will probably still need a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` MOC.
From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/):

> The context is associated with the main queue, and as such is tied
>   into the application’s event loop, but it is otherwise similar to a
>   private queue-based context. You use this queue type for contexts
>   linked to controllers and UI objects that are required to be used only
>   on the main thread.

As an example, for a fetched results controller, you would use the 
`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` MOC.

Comment: Yes, I do need both MOCs.  A simple test proved it to myself.  If I use a single MOC and it is busy writing data in the background, trying to fetch data from it while doing UI stuff crashes the app.  This seems very obvious now that I've tried it.

Comment: Would there be any problem with having only one context initialized with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and use it on multiple threads in the app if all operations on this context were made inside performBlock method? Assuming that we would not pass NSManagedObjects outside of the block passed to performBlock (but instead for example convert those NSManagedObjects to Dictionaries/Codable inside performBlock and pass only them outside of that block instead of NSManagedObjects) would there still be any problem with such approach?